# How to Customize the Apigee-To-Go Console (Styles)

Tags: apigee

Is there any documentation at all related to the Style tab (2. Style) when creating an apigee-to-go console?

I'm creating a new console-to-go.
I've successfully uploaded my WADL and the console is working.

However, I'd like to do some color changing (and so on).

Does anyone have any examples of this that work?
(I've tried a lot of different things, but I'm just guessing.)
There seems to be no documentation on the site.  Googling has turned up nothing.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Best,

Jeff Seltzer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears they may be a bug in the 2. Style section of the console-to-go.  The applied CSS should be visible and editable in the text area box below the Customize your Console section.   I would file a support ticket with Apigee on this one at http://apigee.com/about/support/request-support.

Regards,
-Cesar

Comment: That link works.  Also, you can email help@apigee.com as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed this issue. You should be able to see the default CSS in the Style tab now.
Let us know if you have any concerns.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick turnaround.